# What is the expense of passing a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have an iterative function, phi, that calls itself many times to return the correct result.

```
def phi(n, primes, phis):
```

where primes is a list of primes, 1 < n < 10,000,000
and phis is a list of totient values over the same range of n.

Is it expensive computation-wise to do this in Python? My guess is it does not cost much as we are dealing with pointers in Python so all that will get passed is the pointer? However with this function even the POINTERS would get passed a lot (read: sh##load). Is that computationally expensive?

Comment: Is your code slow? This isn't what's slowing it down, so if it is, profile and make that faster.

Comment: @Julian No - this is an idea I'm considering actually. The function actually uses smaller phi(k), phi(i), etc. to calculate phi(n). So if it already knows those smaller phi(k), phi(i), etc. the process will be much faster. Instead what my function currently does is compute these smaller values millions of times. So hence I'm looking at passing a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, you are not passing the whole list but a pointer. You'll be incurring the regular overhead for function calls which will be much more than the passing of a pointer/parameter.

Comment: Be careful if you ever follow this pattern using `multiprocessing` though.  In that case, you would be pickling and unpickling the entire list for each spawned child.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks. Is there any way to find out how much these respective overheads are, out of curiousity? Is timeit the only reasonable way to do it?

Comment: @Daenyth I had actually found my way to that part of the library moments before you mentioned it :- )

Comment: @nebffa The profiling link provided by Daenyth is a good place to start (you already know about timeit)